# Python creating double list from text file

Tags: python, list, file

How would I around to creating a list filed with list elements that are in a text file, i.e:

I have a text file with

```
car;horse;bike
cat;dog;platypus
salad;cookie;pasta
```

And I'd like to create a list

```
List = [[car;horse;bike],[cat;dog;platypus],[salad;cookie;pasta]]
```

Thanks

Comment: `[[car;horse;bike],[cat;dog;platypus],[salad;cookie;pasta]]` is not valid python syntax, did you mean: `[['car', 'horse', 'bike'], ['cat', 'dog', 'platypus'], ['salad', 'cookie', 'pasta']]`

Comment: The above can be accomplished with literally 3 lines of code: `import csv ; 
with open("data.csv","r") as f :  data = list(csv.reader(f,delimiter=";"))`

Comment: SO is not a code writing service; come with a specific question if you can't figure out how to do something *but have made an effort yourself*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one line:

```
lst = [line.replace('\n','').split(';') for line in open('file.txt','r').readlines()]
```

If you don't put "replace('\n','')" maybe you have problems in the last value. And sometimes you nedd put "replace('\r','')". This is for delete the "return" in the end of line.

Or, easier, as suggested:

lst = [line.strip().split(';') for line in open('file.txt','r').readlines()]

wich produces:

```
[['car', 'horse', 'bike'], ['cat', 'dog', 'platypus'], ['salad', 'cookie', 'past
a']]
```

Comment: why wouldn't you just do `line.strip()`? It removes all white space around the line, including `\n`, `\r`, `\t`, ` ` (space) and a few others.

Comment: Yeah, it is easier, I'll edit. Thanks!

Comment: How could I refer to an element in the list, such as dog. I've tried lst[1][1], put that doesnt work.

Comment: @Johny, did you try the last one I edit? I tried here for lst[1][1] and I got dog.

Comment: I didn't see the edit. Many thanks!!